# how can I solve error in inserting data into database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

[image]
i have a form to fill in done by PHP after filling the form it should transfer the information to a database but it shows me this error every time i press the submit button

Comment: share error and the code. So, that we can help you

Comment: Paste images instead of link to them.

Comment: Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html for reserved words.

Answer (score 1):

Sara...make sure you are not using reserved keywords as column name. Try changing your column name date to some created_date or something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the empty values with NULL. Your code should be like this

```
INSERT INTO asset (type, kind, new, obtain, owner, quantity, date, condition) VALUES ('Hardware', NULL, 'yes', 'Purchase', 'Center', NULL, NULL, 'new')
```